# Bootstrap typeahead with json object instead of string

Tags: javascript, json, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I got typeahead working by handing bootstrap a simple flat json array of strings like `["php","php4","php5"]`. All of the standard functions do what I want in this case.

However I'd like to give the data in a format like the following:

```
[
    {
        "name":"php",
        "count":123
    },
    {
        "name":"php4",
        "count":3532
    },
    {
        "name":"php5",
        "count":999
    }
]
```

And with that I'd like to format my typeahead to use both name and count. Perhaps produce something that looks like **php5 (999)** and when you choose the typeahead it will just output **php5**. I figured it would be easy to do if I just override all of the functions.

```
$('.input-classname').typeahead({
        source: function (query, process) {
            // Source here
        },
        updater: function (item) { // What gets sent to the input box
            return item.name;
        },
        highlighter: function(item) {
            return item.name + " (" + item.count + ")";
        },
        matcher: function (item) {
            // Do the matching
        },
        sorter: function (items) {
            // Do the sorting
        }
    });
```

This works fine but I'd like to use the *base* versions of `highlighter`, `matcher`, and `sorter` to do the grunt work. And I'd just pass in `item.name` instead of the `item`. However I don't know how to get at the base versions of these functions. Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just call/apply the methods on the `Typeahead` prototype, e.g.

```
var Typeahead = $.fn.typeahead.Constructor;

$(".input-classname").typeahead({
  // ...
  matcher: function (item) {
    // do something with item
    return Typeahead.prototype.matcher.call(this, item);
  },

  sorter: function (items) {
    // alternatively
    // do something with items
    return this.constructor.prototype.sorter.call(this, items);
  }
});
```

Comment: Sorter won't work. It accepts a list of strings, not a list of objects - if you map object names to strings, then highlighter item.name won't work.

Comment: The point of the answer was how to monkey patch prototype methods while being able to call the originals.  Updated code to make the two examples just pass through.